# Cannot get ValidatorPipe to work with nest.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-validator

#### Current behavior

When I try to initialize a validation pipe for a request body, nothing happens when an invalid type is given.

#### Expected behavior

When the user specifies a value that goes against the type in my DTO, I reject with an error. In this case, I request /test with a body of

`{ "string": true }`

I expect this to error but it does not.

#### Minimal reproduction of the problem

[Test DTO](https://gist.github.com/RTK99/1b60661aeede68b3ae4fa15e1cc5278a)

```
import { IsString } from "class-validator";
export class TestDTO {
  @IsString() public readonly string: string;
}
```

[Test Controller](https://gist.github.com/RTK99/72d6558c9263685a654d69486a70a4b0)

```
@Controller()
export class TestController {
  @Post("/test")
  public testing(@Body(new ValidationPipe()) test: TestDTO): string {
    return test.string;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me, throws an 404 on `{"string": true}`. Does `return test.string` actually return a boolean in your case? Otherwise try to reinstall your `node_modules` and update your dependencies with `npm update`.

Comment: Yes @KimKern it returns a boolean. I'll try reinstalling node modules. Im using fastify adapter if that has anything to do with it.
And also, why is it throwing a 404? Shouldn't it be throwing a 400 (BAD_REQUEST)?

Comment: Yup, it's a 400. Sorry ;)

Comment: Yea. Reinstalled node modules, same result.
May I ask you: are you using express or fastify adapter?

Comment: I've tried it with express

Comment: Could you do me a favor and swap in the fastify module for testing?

Comment: It also returns a 400 with fastify. That's not the problem. You can try it out in an empty project yourself.

Comment: @itexlo, I'm currently facing the same issue; Was wondering if you found the solution to your problem ? If yes, could you please share it with me please ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Change "class-transformer" to "<=0.4.0" as 0.4.1 was an accidental patch release for a major change and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

When the body contains boolean, the backend (nestjs) parse it as a string
There is a decorator to validate if parameter has boolean as a string

```
@IsBooleanString()
myVariable:boolean;
```

What you can do in your case:

- **Option 1**

You can stransform your body value from boolean to number

```
From { "string": true } To { "string": 1 }
```

- **Option 2**

You can use an extra [validate decorator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-decorators), the `@IsNotIn(values: any[])`
example:

```
@IsString()
@IsNotIn(["FALSE", "TRUE"])
myVariable: string;
```

- **Option 3**

You can create your [own decorator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-decorators)

```
import { registerDecorator, ValidationOptions, ValidationArguments } from 'class-validator';

export function IsNotBoolean(validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
  return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      name: 'IsNotBoolean',
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      constraints: [],
      options: validationOptions,
      validator: {
        validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
         if(value.toUpperCase() == 'TRUE' || value.toUpperCase() == 'FALSE'){
          return false
         } else {
          return true
         }
        },
      },
    });
  };
}
```

On the DTO

```
import { IsString } from "class-validator";
import { IsNotBoolean } from "the path of your custom validate decorator"

export class TestDTO {
  @IsString({myErrorKey:'My error message'}) 
  @IsNotBoolean({the optional error message object})
  string: string;
}
```

On the Controller

```
public testing(@Body(ValidationPipe) test: TestDTO): string {
    return test.string;
}
```